# Transform ImageMagick's convert command to RMagick

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, rmagick

I want to detect if an image is fully black. I use the following command:

```
convert /path/to/image.png -format "%[mean]" info:
```

it returns 0 if the image is fully black and non-zero value otherwise.

How can I rewrite it using RMagick gem?